# Show $[\mathbb{Q}(\cos\frac{\theta}{3}, \cos\theta): \mathbb{Q}(\cos\theta)]=2$ implies that $\theta$ is trisectable using straightedge and compass.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, extension-field, geometric-construction

Show $[\mathbb{Q}(\cos\frac{\theta}{3}, \cos\theta): \mathbb{Q}(\cos\theta)]=2$ implies that $\theta$ is trisectable using straightedge and compass.

**Proof**: $[\mathbb{Q}(\cos\frac{\theta}{3}, \cos\theta): \mathbb{Q}(\cos\theta)]=2$ implies that $\mathbb{Q}(\cos\frac{\theta}{3}, \cos\theta)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\alpha})$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(\cos\theta)$. Let $P=\{0, 1, \cos\theta\}$, then clearly $\mathbb{Q}(P)=\mathbb{Q}(\cos\theta)$, hence $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\alpha}): \mathbb{Q}(P)]=[\mathbb{Q}(\cos\frac{\theta}{3}, \cos\theta): \mathbb{Q}(\cos\theta)]=2$, thus $\sqrt{\alpha}\in \mathbb{Q}(P)^{py}$, where $\mathbb{Q}(P)^{py}$ is the Pythagorean closure. Therefore $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\alpha}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(P)^{py}$.

Now, $\cos\frac{\theta}{3}\in \mathbb{Q}(\cos\frac{\theta}{3}, \cos\theta)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\alpha})$, hence $\cos\frac{\theta}{3} \in \mathbb{Q}(P)^{py}$, meaning $\cos\frac{\theta}{3}$ is constructible from $P$, and it follows that $\theta$ can be trisected. QED.

I am a bit skeptical about my application of the theorem involving the Pythagorean closure $\mathbb{Q}(P)^{py}$. Please verify the proof if you can-many thanks in advance!

Comment: You could have edited the previous questions ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4399961/prove-that-if-the-polynomial-4t3-3t-cos-theta-is-reducible-over-mathbbq), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4399972/show-if-mathbb-q-cos-theta-cos-frac-theta3-mathbb-q-cos-theta-1), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4399990/show-if-mathbb-q-cos-theta-cos-frac-theta3-mathbb-q-cos-theta-1)) to clarify, instead of deleting and reposting.

Comment: @dxiv I see. If that is recommended, I will definitely do that in the future-this is more of a proof-verification request than a question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a special case of: If $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are given (or constructible) and $[F:\Bbb Q(a_1,\ldots, a_n)]=2$, then every $a\in F$ is constructible from the givens. One can use Pythagorean closure as you did, but might as well use directly that quadratic equations (with constructible coefficients) can be solved with straight-edge and compasses.

Comment: Thank you so much for the insight!